# How do I remove the alert: "...may not respond to..."

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, compiler-construction, warnings

In my `.m` file I call a method that is inside the same `.m` file. In the header I have the correct import for the header but I keep getting this alert:

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-04-11_2222.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-04-11_2222.png)

What am I doing wrong? What should I do in order to make this error disappear? I'm kinda lost here :-(

Even if I changed this to:

```
NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] 
   initWithString:@"...."];
[self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];
[path release];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just declare the method in your `.h` file.  Or move the method implementation ahead of where it is called, if it's not going to be called from another class.

Answer (score 0):

In you implementation file (BlogViewController.m), add an extension interface like so:

```
@interface BlogViewController ()
- (void) parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL;
@end

@implementation BlogViewController 
...
```

This tells the compiler to expect the method but keeps it protected if no external object needs to call it.

Comment: ty, but as a beginner I rather put interface stuff in the `.h` file (header) :)